# using media_sideload_image with a file from theme directory

Tags: images, uploads

I'm building a Wordpress site in which an admin can upload a video file from post metabox.

After that post is saved and the video file is attached to the post, I used ffmpeg to get the screenshot at the first second of video, then save this screenshot as a JPG file in 'tmp' directory in theme directory.

Finally, I want to programmatically make this screenshot as post featured image. I use media_sideload_image function, which generally be used to get image from another server and set that image as post featured image and I think this function could be used in this case also.

In my case, the video screenshot was successfully saved to 'tmp' directory in my theme dir, but the media_sideload_image part did not return anything for further process. Here's my function:

```
function create_video_featured_image($post_id, $image_uri) {

// $image_uri = 'http://localhost/demo-site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/tmp/video_thumb_952.jpg';
$media = media_sideload_image($image_uri, $post_id);

if(!empty($media) && !is_wp_error($media)){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => $post_id
    );

    // reference new image to set as featured
    $attachments = get_posts($args);

    if(isset($attachments) && is_array($attachments)){
        foreach($attachments as $attachment){
            // grab source of full size images (so no 300x150 nonsense in path)
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
            // determine if in the $media image we created, the string of the URL exists
            if(strpos($media, $image[0]) !== false){
                // if so, we found our image. set it as thumbnail
                set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment->ID);
                // only want one image
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Am I missing anything or is there another way to work around in this case ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Please include the following files before using media_sideload_image() for it to work,

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

Reference, [WP Codex: media_sideload_image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My function is called via 'save_post' filter so I think including those files is not necessary. Anyway, I have tried to include those files to my theme functions.php but it still does not work. The video screenshot is still generated and saved successfully to 'tmp' dir in my theme dir (I can get its url and save in a post meta), but the media_sideload_image function does not return anything...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over all the attachments, since the media_sideload_image function returns the attachment ID if you pass 'id' as the fourth argument.

Then it could be simplified to something like this:

```
function create_video_featured_image($post_id, $image_uri) {    
$image_uri = 'http://localhost/demo-site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/tmp/video_thumb_952.jpg';
$media_id = media_sideload_image($image_uri, $post_id, null, 'id');
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $media_id);
}
```